# add each tuple with a certain number

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples representing x,y coordinates and I want to add each tuple with a certain number. For example, say that I want to change `my_list = [(2,1), (2,2)]` to `[(2+n,1+n), (2+n,2+n)]` where `n=0` in this case.

How can I do this?

My attempt:

```py
my_tuples = [(2, 1), (2, 2)]


def hector(p_list):
    n = 0
    for i in range(len(p_list)):
        (x, y) = (p_list[i])
    return x + n, y + n


print(hector(my_tuples))
```

Output:

```py
1,2
```

Desired output:

```py
[(2,1), (2,2)]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: tuples are immutable, so you would need to convert it to a list then back to a tuple

Comment: Your desired output and code are invalid due to an extra bracket and incorrect indenting, respectively. I tried fixing it on my machine, but I got different output. Please provide a [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Are you sure the output was `1,2`? I got `(2, 2)`

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in doing `n=0` that wouldn't change the tuples, but here is how you can do it with a list comprehension.

```
n = 1 
my_tuples = [(2,1), (2,2)]
my_tuples = [(x + n, y + n) for (x, y) in my_tuples]
# [(3, 2), (3, 3)]
```